# Email from one sender disapears, without rules setup

Tags: email

I receive e-mails from one marketplace on several mail accounts, but e-mails disappear after about a minute. I can see them pop-up in my inbox (outlook or android) and, without doing anything, after a minute or so the mail is gone. Not deleted or moved, but completly gone. This doesn't happen with all mails from them, but only with payment reminders.

I have checked for any rules, but the few rules I have only move items. So even an unsuspected rule would leave the mail somewhere.

What are the options I can check to how the email is removed? Could it be that the sender retracts the mail some how?

Comment: Do other people have access to the mailbox, and as such, may it be a colleague that moves the mail?

Comment: Especially one who might not want you to know of outstanding bills?

Comment: It's a private inbox, just for me. Even handled by two different providers and both with different usernames and passwords. (private and business mail)